# I want to clone a javascript class. add methods to the cloned property without actually overwriting the exisiting methods?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototypejs

I am trying to add methods to a cloned a prototype class property. I have pasted the code below.

At the moment when i add methods to this snippet of code it over writes whats been defined in the super class.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.3/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var Animal = Class.create({
    initialize: function(name, sound) {
    this.name  = name;
    this.sound = sound;
    },

    speak: function() {
    alert(this.name + " says: " + this.sound + "!");
    }
});

Animal.movement = {
    move: function(direction){
        alert('moving: ' + direction)
    }
}

var AnimalClone = { }
Object.extend(AnimalClone, Animal);

//Now i want to add 'jump' to this list of methods 
//without over writing the inherited 'move' method
AnimalClone.movement = {
    jump: function(height){
        alert('jumped:' + height)
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *extend* the `movement` object, not overwrite it:

```
Object.extend(AnimalClone.movement, {
    jump: function(height){
        alert('jumped:' + height)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As `movement` is an object, you have to extend it also by accessing it using the prototype

```
var Animal = Class.create({
    initialize: function(name, sound) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sound = sound;
    },
    movement: {
        move: function(direction) {
            alert('moving: ' + direction);
        }
    }
});

var AnimalClone = Class.create({});
AnimalClone.prototype = Object.extend(new Animal(),{});

AnimalClone.prototype.movement = Object.extend(AnimalClone.prototype.movement, {
        jump: function(height) {
            alert('jumped:' + height);
        }
});

var animalClone = new AnimalClone;
animalClone.movement.move("up");
animalClone.movement.jump("10mts");
```